# Handling errors during Entity Framework database operations

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, silverlight

I want to handle errors such as foreign-key violations during Entity Framework database operations.  So, when a user updates, inserts, or deletes a record using the framework, I want to catch sql errors and show them a cleaner, readable error message. Currently, without the error handling, the application is left in a broken state and an error message pops up with a long, specific stacktrace.

I have had trouble finding a clean solution to this problem.  Any help is appreciated!

Also, I'm using the Entity Framework, in combination with Silverlight and WCF data services.

Comment: Using try .. catch ( SpecificExceptionType ex) will be good. Then you know the problem, and you can make a good message as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most common solution to this would be to write try/catch in your code.
Or you could use a Generic Repository pattern as suggested in the following link -

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf1f6e46-28d8-427f-a259-00f85b403238/entity-framework-centralized-exception-handling

Answer (score 0):

This task is really hard because the errors that throw EF are many and the possible cause for that errors are more. My recommendation is to use a repository pattern. If you want to easy create the repository pattern you can have something generic for all your entities